# Not able to fetch website data using Importxml in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to fetch this website (https://www.covidhotspots.in/?city=Mumbai&source=share) data using Importxml in Google Sheets but it gives me no data.

I am trying to apply below formula but it is giving me #NA

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.covidhotspots.in/?city=Mumbai&source=share","//li/text()")
```

I want to fetch geocodes as mentioned in the below images

[image: Need to fetch geo code]

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

`IMPORTXML` can only read the HTML source of a website. Therefore, those elements and components of a website added dynamically will not be able to be retrieved by the `IMPORTXML`.

If in your browser you take a look and view the source of the website, specifically focusing on the parent `ul` element that contains the `li` that you want to retrieve, you will find that the `ul` element is empty. This is because the children are inserted dynamically throughout a Javascript script (and that is why when you call this `IMPORTXML` accordinly to that `ul` nothing is returned, because it is empty in the source HTML).

## Possible workaround

Sometimes, in the Javascript files of the website, you can find out the URL of the source of data being inserted dynamically but that is a tedious task to achieve.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Thanks @Mateo for clarification, there is an  API they are using  [https://geoiq.io/covid19.html] . Can u please help how to use that ?

Comment: Hi ! For using their API it is best you create a new question if you have any doubts on how to implement it as in this question is out of scope. Thanks !